# Reset Singleton for each Unit Test - Java

Tags: java, junit, singleton

I've unit tests and when I run them one by one they pass. But If I run them together they fail after first one. Because in tests I'm checking if a file is created and my singleton class creates it. But it does not create files if its initialized and should stay that way. So without changing the code of the singleton class I need to reset singleton for each test.

I tried the code below but sadly didn't work, it doesnt create the files.

```
 @Before
public void resetSingleton() throws Exception {
   Field instance = MySingleton.class.getDeclaredField("instance");
   instance.setAccessible(true);
   instance.set(null, null);
}
```

And my class basically summarized like this:

```
private static MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();

static { 
observer = new MyObserver(instance);
}

public static MySingleton getInstance(){
if(instance == null){
instance = new MySingleton();
}
return instance;
```

**Edit**:

There's a method inside if the singleton is not running it writes back-up logs, if its running it presumes it already did. But this state keeps transferred between unit tests. Thats my problem.

Comment: Unit tests should ideally be stateless and also not dependent on each other.  If you are actually writing/checking a file, then strictly speaking you are running _integration_ tests.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen They're not dependent, only dependency is that singleton class. Think of it as a log unit. I'm testing that unit to create a file and delete it afterwards to try out a different message from a different function.

Comment: That is why singleton pattern can be convenient to implement but it's very troublesome to unit test.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the tests to see whether the constructor of the singleton is executed? I would expect resetting the field via reflection to work, unless the `instance`-field is also `final`.

Comment: @Hulk there's a method inside if the singleton is not running it writes back-up logs, if its running it presumes it already did. But this state keeps transferred between unit tests. Thats my problem.

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu Then this problem is totally of a different scope. It means you need to "hijack" into that part as well, which *may* require you to change the actual code, depending on how it's written.

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu how does this "backup-writing" method distinguish "running" and "not-running"? Does it just check the `instance` for `null`? Put a breakpoint in there to see why it does what it does...

Comment: @Hulk  Not a null check but it receives a state from another application something like running or not-running. But when I start a unit test it starts as not-running then becomes running. All my tests are like this and they work as intended if I run them separately.  I debugged that part and it stays "running" and thats the problem I'm trying to solve. Thing is I cant change that code. So I need to reset everything(or at least singleton) at before class of that test.

Comment: @Jai Thing is I cant change that code. So I need to reset everything(or at least singleton) at before class of that test

Comment: "receives a state from another application" - How? Can you just mock that receiving part out somehow? This increasingly sounds like a full integration test for a multi-application system, and that is something UnitTest-frameworks are not intended to be used for (and therefore not yery good at). You should try to avoid depending on any kind of state in a unit test, least of all the state of some other application.

Comment: @Hulk I know, I know but cant change the class and mocking would not be good. I want a solution as the code I asked in the question.

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu well, if you don't want to mock it, you'll need to somehow "restart" this other application before each test

Answer (score -3):

Singleton is considered to be an anti pattern mostly (not only) for theses reasons. it is much harder to create isolated unit tests. especially if you described it in the comments that there is some third party who controls the fact if the singleton is running or not.
If possible - remove this implementation and make sure your context creates one instance and pass it to whoever needs it - IOC container as Spring for Java would make things much easier.
if the singleton creates a file one time and that's the expected behavior, then you can test that the file is being created only by one test.

Comment: The code above works usually (resetSingleton), I'm in need of some modifications for it. Because of the static { 
observer = new MyObserver(instance);
} part of mySingleton

Comment: I understand, does the implementation of
static { 
observer = new MyObserver(instance);
}  has to be this way? if so you can check out powermock framework to override the static initialization but in general if it is possible for you - I would change the initialization to be somewhere else and not in the static initialization of the Singleton